# Capturing Atlas geometry using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, atlas

I have a QgsLayoutAtlas,  I need to capture the geometry of each sheet within a  loop

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
layout = project.layoutManager().layoutByName('Layout')
atlas=layout.atlas ()
hojas=atlas.count ()
i=0
for i in range(hojas):
    atlas.seekTo(i)
    #HERE I NEED THE GEOMETRY OF @atlas_geometry
    i=+1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to loop on the coverage layer instead

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
layout = project.layoutManager().layoutByName('Layout')
atlas = layout.atlas ()

for i, feature in enumerate(atlas.coverageLayer().getFeatures()):
    atlas.seekTo(i)
    print(feature.geometry())
```